# Filter dataframe according to month from timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have two filters for months:

```
oct_may = [1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12]
jun_sep = [6,7,8,9]
```

Suppose I have a Dataframe like this:

```
> Timestamp max con pf

3/21/2017 23:00 123 232 0.91
3/22/2017 0:00  122 232 0.91
8/22/2017 1:00  122 232 0.92
3/22/2017 2:00  121 232 0.91
3/22/2017 3:00  118 232 0.89
9/22/2017 4:00  120 232 0.9
3/22/2017 5:00  121 232 0.91
3/22/2017 6:00  123 232 0.89
```

I want to get the data from "con" column, based on the months lying between the above mentioned two filters of the month (`oct_may` and `jun_sep`).

I have tried `df.loc[df.index.month]` but I am unable to get the data.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first convert index to [`DatetimeIndex.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html) and then check with [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) because output of `DatetimeIndex.month` is `numpy array`:

```
#if necessary
#df.index= pd.to_datetime(df.index)

print (type(df.index.month))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

df1 = df[np.in1d(df.index.month, oct_may)]
print (df1)
                     max  con    pf
Timestamp                          
2017-03-21 23:00:00  123  232  0.91
2017-03-22 00:00:00  122  232  0.91
2017-03-22 02:00:00  121  232  0.91
2017-03-22 03:00:00  118  232  0.89
2017-03-22 05:00:00  121  232  0.91
2017-03-22 06:00:00  123  232  0.89

df2 = df[np.in1d(df.index.month, jun_sep)]
print (df2)
                     max  con    pf
Timestamp                          
2017-08-22 01:00:00  122  232  0.92
2017-09-22 04:00:00  120  232  0.90
```

---

For pure pandas solution convert to `Series` and compare with `isin`:

```
df1 = df[pd.Series(df.index.month, index=df.index).isin(oct_may)]
print (df1)
                     max  con    pf
Timestamp                          
2017-03-21 23:00:00  123  232  0.91
2017-03-22 00:00:00  122  232  0.91
2017-03-22 02:00:00  121  232  0.91
2017-03-22 03:00:00  118  232  0.89
2017-03-22 05:00:00  121  232  0.91
2017-03-22 06:00:00  123  232  0.89
```

Comment: Timestamp is the index of the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `loc` you need to generate a boolean mask or a list of things that are in the index.  However, if you create a boolean mask, its syntactically simpler to forgo the `df.loc[mask]` and just use `df[mask]`

This is what a solution using `loc` and indices looks like

```
df.set_index(
    df.index.month, append=True
).sort_index().loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, oct_may], :].reset_index(1, drop=True)

                     max  con    pf
Timestamp                          
2017-03-21 23:00:00  123  232  0.91
2017-03-22 00:00:00  122  232  0.91
2017-03-22 02:00:00  121  232  0.91
2017-03-22 03:00:00  118  232  0.89
2017-03-22 05:00:00  121  232  0.91
2017-03-22 06:00:00  123  232  0.89
```

That's ugly, in my opinion.

Using a mask is the way to go.

```
df[df.index.to_series().dt.month.isin(oct_may)]
​
                     max  con    pf
Timestamp                          
2017-03-21 23:00:00  123  232  0.91
2017-03-22 00:00:00  122  232  0.91
2017-03-22 02:00:00  121  232  0.91
2017-03-22 03:00:00  118  232  0.89
2017-03-22 05:00:00  121  232  0.91
2017-03-22 06:00:00  123  232  0.89
```